# Generating PEP8 xml report for Jenkins/Violations use

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've setup Cobertura successfully to run through Jenkins and generate coverage reports, now I'm stuck on configuring Violations to report results for pep8 tests.

Right now I have it so that I run PEP8 with a batch command and it generate a .txt file that stores all the violations which ends up in the workspace.

Do I have to define batch commands to create an xml file for these violations to send to the Report Violations Post-build action? If so, how would I define that command?

Comment: AFAIK adding the pep8 output file name (inside the workspace) in the row for pep8 in report violations is the only step you need to do to let the results show up in jenkins...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As Vajk points out, you do not need an XML file. You can simply pipe the output of the pep8 utility to a file and use that as the violations file in Jenkins.

For example in your Jenkins build configuration under:

```
Build -> Execute Shell -> Command
```

you can write:

```
pep8 path/to/code > pep8_report.txt
```

And then under:

```
Post-build Actions -> Report Violations -> pep8 / XML filename pattern
```

add:

```
pep8_report.txt
```

Note that even though the UI asks for an XML file and the file is not an XML file, this worked fine for me on Jenkins version 1.499.

Comment: You can also use [flake8](https://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.0/index.html) output as pep8 violations.

Comment: I have tried like the above and it worked for me too but the problem is links in the violations are not working.

Comment: I'm not able to see the 'Report Violations' in 'post-build action'. Am I missing a plugin? (I have Cobertura installed already).

Comment: 'Report Violations' requires the 'Violations' plugin which is no longer maintained. The plugin page itself recommends the warning plugin which doesn't fit everything violations plugin covered.

Comment: This is great, however on the violations output in jenkins, when I click into a violation I am getting "No violations found" :-(

Comment: Okay, so my problem is that the Report Violations option in the Post build actions, is inactive in that I can't click it. So what could be the reason for that, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I see this a very old question but I had a lot of trouble myself to find an answer to this, so hopefully this will help others.

After a lot of research I found that Jenkins Violations plugin does not like the ./ bit before each line, so just parsing the output of pep8 (it is also valid for flake8) will do the trick:

`pep8 . | 's|^./||' | tee pep.txt`

The important bit in there is sed which changes the occurrences of ./ at the beginning of the string(^) to '', effectively removing them

The tee bit is some workaround to avoid Jenkins halting if the output of the pep8 command is non-zero.